# how to check a dynamic column name is null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like below which has several columns along with series of numbers as well like the below:

Name: `JLEDG`

| name | user_val_1 | user_val_2 | user_val_3 | user_val_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Three | Three |

`DECLARE @myvar int = 3;`

So I would like to do the following which is not working:

`SELECT * FROM JLEDG WHERE ('user_val_' + @myvar) IS NULL;`

Expect the sql should be

`SELECT * FROM JLEDG WHERE user_val_3 IS NULL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only do that in dynamic SQL.  You seem to have a problem with your data model.  You shouldn't be storing values splayed across columns like that.  You should have *another* table with one row per value.

One thing you can do is unpivot (using `apply`) and then filter:

```
select j.*
from jledg j cross apply
     (values (1, user_val_1), (2, user_val_2), . . . 
     ) v(which, user_val)
where which = @myvar;
```

The alternative is to use dynamic SQL (`sp_executesql`), but that seems quite cumbersome when you could just fix the data model.

Comment: Thanks, @Gordonlinoff. Unfortunately, I can't change any of the existing stuff. Is it possible to provide some examples of using `sp_executesql` please?

Comment: @Sri . . . The suggested query does not requiring changing any "existing stuff".

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is declarative by design, and does not support macro substitution.  As Gordon mentioned in his solution (+1), Dynamic SQL is just another option

**Example**

```
 Declare @myvar int = 3
 Declare @SQL varchar(max) = concat('SELECT * FROM JLEDG WHERE user_val_',@myvar,' IS NULL;')
 Exec(@SQL)
```